# Disable theme debug.. just in one field

Tags: theming, entities, 8

Is it possible to disable theme debug in one field? I don't want to disable theme debug, but when I set up background file from field, theme debug comments block this style functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You would need to hack core in order to do it (`twig_render_template`), which might be ok for your local development.

The code in interest is this part:

```
if ($twig_service->isDebug()) {
  $output['debug_prefix'] .= "\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->";
  ...
}
```

You could add a condition, like this:

```
 if ($twig_service->isDebug() && $template_file != 'awesome-template-file') {
```

I'm not sure what `$template_file` looks like, but I'm sure you could use it to make a condition to make the template file in question be skipped debug. This actually requires that the field uses it's own template file though.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but you can do the following:

```
      $twig_service = \Drupal::service('twig');
      $was_debugging = FALSE;
      if ($twig_service->isDebug()) {
        $was_debugging = TRUE;
        $twig_service->disableDebug();
      }

...
Do your thing.
...


      if ($was_debugging) {
        $twig_service->enableDebug();
      }
```